# How to solve this Error .. hibernate session Too many connection error

Tags: java, hibernate

this is java class

1.a few second after throwing a too many connection error?
how to solve this

2.org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

3.com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

```
package MVC;
import POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetAss;
import POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetils;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.FlushMode;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
public class thread_servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void Search_Timeout_Details() throws Exception {
        //Create Main While
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (true) {
                    Session s = Connection.connector.getSessionFactory().openSession();enter code here
                    Criteria c = s.createCriteria(POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetils.class);
                    c.add(Restrictions.eq("timeoutState", "1"));
                    c.add(Restrictions.eq("state", "1"));
                    List<POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetils> ptd = c.list();

                    if (ptd.isEmpty()) {

                        System.out.println("no");
                    } else {

                        System.out.println("yes");

                        for (TheaterBookingSeatDetils tnsd : ptd) {

                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:s");

                            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                            Date sd = now.getTime();
                            String current_date = sdf.format(sd);
                            String current_time = sdft.format(sd);

                            try {
                                Date date1 = sdf.parse(current_date);
                                Date date2 = sdf.parse(tnsd.getTimeoutDate());
                                Date date3 = sdft.parse(tnsd.getTimeoutTime());
                                Date date4 = sdft.parse(current_time);

                                if (date1.equals(date2)) {

                                    if (date4.equals(date3) | date3.before(date4)) {

                                        int id = tnsd.getIdtheaterBookingSeatDetils();
                                        POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetils ptb = (POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetils) s.load(POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetils.class, id);

                                        System.out.println(ptb.getIdtheaterBookingSeatDetils());

                                        //db eken remove wenna code karanna one
                                        //
                                        Criteria cc = s.createCriteria(POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetAss.class);
                                        List<POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetAss> ll = cc.add(Restrictions.eq("theaterBookingSeatDetils", ptb)).list();

                                        if (ll.isEmpty()) {

                                        } else {

                                            for (TheaterBookingSeatDetAss ptas : ll) {

                                                s.delete(s.load(POJOs.TheaterBookingSeatDetAss.class, ptas.getIdtheaterBookingSeatDetAss()));

                                            }
                                        }

                                        s.delete(ptb);
                                        s.beginTransaction().commit();

                                        System.out.println("time Deleted");

                                    }

                                } else if (date2.before(date1)) {

                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }    
                        }    
                    }

                    s.clear();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }    
                }    
            }    
        }).start();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        thread_servlet ts = new thread_servlet();
        ts.Search_Timeout_Details();
    }    
}
```

Comment: What does `Connection.connector.closee()` do? What does `Connection.connector.doWork()` do? P.S. **YOU DON'T CLOSE YOUR `Session`**.

Comment: As an aside, when you post on this side **always** use Java naming conventions. Classes are in `PascalCase` and variables are in `camelCase`. No exceptions. No Excuses. `snake_case` is for Python, not Java.

Comment: i not close the session but is not work ?

Comment: You run out of connections because you don't close them. It's as simple as that.

Comment: i close the session object but is not work .. i clear the session object that work to few time after it throws the that error ..

Comment: You don't close the `Session`. You `clear()` the `Session`.

Comment: my previous code that do it .. it work but is not update my front end ...

Comment: Well that's a different problem. This code is wrong because you don't `close()` the `Session`. The other code was wrong for a different reason. I would suggest you delete this question and ask another with the other code. **After correcting the naming as mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357920/how-to-solve-this-error-hibernate-session-too-many-connection-error?noredirect=1#comment67969263_40357920)**.

Comment: s.clear //object update my front end